# How do address these WARNING's when I open firefox from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, firefox

When I open my Firefox Web Browser from the terminal I get these following warnings.

```
william@william-AO722:~$ firefox
(process:5672): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
(firefox:5672): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
(firefox:5672): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
(firefox:5672): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
(firefox:5672): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
```

Is there a way that I can get rid of these warnings?

Also can anyone tell me what GLib is and what is it for?

I am running Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: you can just ignore warnings, as long as the program doesn't crash or give **errors** you're fine.

Comment: Other than getting the warnings, everything seems to run fine. I guess I can just ignore them for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is closely related to [Why are there so many console messages from GTK+ applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications).

For the specific GLib error with Firefox please see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833117.

To know how to disable these errors look at [Disable css warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195495/disable-css-warnings) and this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/198385/248158 which suggests "redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`".

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to care about these developer messages and warning.

You as a user should open the GTK application (like firefox) without redirecting messages to terminal window like so:

```
nohup firefox &
```

Answer (score 0):

I think those is not warnings for you as an end user. It's just some messages passed to developers or some users that really want to know what is happening:).

Anyway what you need to do is just run your applications in background by inserting & at the end of your command and you'll not see such messages.You can try:

```
firefox &
```

Comment: Putting `&` at the end still shows the console output. You need `>/dev/null 2>&1` to fully suppress output.